# regex regular expression python

Tags: python

I'm having problems with this method in python called findall. I'm accessing a web pages HTML and trying to return the name of a product in this case `'bread'` and print it out to the console.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions.  Many people will tell you this.

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Looks to me like you're getting the number of spaces wrong.  Try `\s+` instead to be less dependent on the count, like `"Item:\s+is in\s+lane 12\s+(\w*)"`.  (Disclaimer: not really tested.)  And while the advice not to use regex to parse HTML is good, while something like BeautifulSoup is going to make it easier to get *at* the text, if you want to extract `bread` *from* the text, you're probably going to wind up using regexes at that point anyway.

Comment: Wow DSM that did the trick I can't believe it just putting \s+. I don't know how the spaces were incorrect. i tried over hundred times even copied and pasted the HTML thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regex for HTML parsing.
There are a few solutions. I suggest BeautifulSoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Having said so, however, in this particular case, RE will suffice. Just relax it a notch. There might be more or less spaces or maybe those are tabs. So instead of literal spaces use the space class **\s**:

```
product = re.findall(r'Item:\s*is\s*in\s*lane\s*12\s*(\w*)', content)
print product[0]
```

Since The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy (they match as much text as possible) you don't need to restrict it with **`[^<]*<br>`**

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want to use regexps, here's a working one for your case:

```
product = re.findall(r'<br>\s*Item:\s+is\s+in\s+lane 12\s+(\w*)[^<]*<br>', content)
```

It takes into account DSM's space flexibility suggestion and non-letters after `(\w*)` that might appear before `<br>`.